# How to write in target folder with right permissions?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

On first workflow, below command is run as `user1` that works fine:

```
docker cp $(docker-compose ps -q builder):/wheelhouse/. target
```

in creating the folder(`target` if not exists) and then copy files to `target` folder from `/wheelhouse`(within container) .

Below is the `target` folder created:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 2         165536         165536    4096 Oct 29 06:20 target
```

---

On second workflow, `user1` cannot run the same command successfully, because `target` folder is owned by `165536` and does not provide permissions to group and others.

---

1) What is owner name `165536` for `target` folder?

2) What is the best practice in terms of creating `target` folder? Which user should generally run `docker-compose.yml` files? Currently am running with login user `user1`... which is not part of any group

Comment: For the user: `grep 165536 /etc/passwd` will show you the user's definition.  However, when you see a number instead of a name, it is usally because the user definition is gone.  Ex. user1, no 123 has files.  user1 is deleted from the system, the files that were owned by user1, are now owned by 123.

Comment: @Nic3500 looks like this problem has something to do with fixing issue in user namespace